# Quicksort returning same vector as passed

Tags: r, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I recently started using `R` and am as an exercise trying to implement quicksort. I am using the book "Introduction to Algorithms (3rd ed)"

I am using `RStudio` and am not seeing any errors, but it returns the same vector as it is passed, am I assuming something wrong? I believe the my code matches what the pseudo code of the book shows. The Psuedo code is as follows:

```
Partition(A, p, r)
  x = A[r]
  i = p - 1
  for j = p to r - 1
     if A[j] <= x
       i = i + 1
       swap(A[i], A[j])
  swap(A[i+1], A[r]
  return i + 1

Quicksort(A, p, r)
  if p < r
    q = Partition(A, p, r)
    Quicksort(A, p, q - 1)
    Quicksort(A, q + 1, r)
```

I than wrote the same two functions in `R`:

```
partition <- function(a, p, r) {
    x = a[r]
    i = p - 1
    for (j in p:(r-1)) {
        if (a[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1
            t = a[i]
            a[i] = a[j]
            a[j] = t
        }
    }
    t = a[i+1]
    a[i+1] = a[r]
    a[r] = t
    i+1
}

quicksort <- function(a, p, r) {
    if (p < r) {
        q = partition(a, p, r)
        quicksort(a, p, q-1)
        quicksort(a, q+1, r)
    }
    a
}
```

In `RStudio`, I source the file and call it with a vector I created:

```
> v
[1] 8 5 6 7 4 1 3 2
> quicksort(v, 1, length(v))
[1] 8 5 6 7 4 1 3 2
```

As far as I have read you are able to do recursive functions in R, I know you can't pass by reference, but wouldnt this be calling the same function with a changed vector? I am confused as to why it is returning the same vector passed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The lack of pass by reference means that you cannot change `a` using the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you want to change an object using a function you have to return it and assign it. I changed your code in two places: the `partition` function returns a list of two items, the vector `a` and the position `i`. In `quicksort`: the result of `partition` is stored initially in `temp` and its items assigned to `a` and `q`. Also, you have to assign the result of each change of `a` back to it.

```
partition <- function(a, p, r) {
  x = a[r]
  i = p - 1
  for (j in p:(r-1)) {
    if (a[j] <= x) {
      i = i + 1
      t = a[i]
      a[i] = a[j]   
      a[j] = t
    }
  }
  t = a[i+1]
  a[i+1] = a[r]
  a[r] = t
  list(i = i+1, a = a)
}

quicksort <- function(a, p, r) {
  if (p < r) {
    temp = partition(a, p, r)
    a <- temp$a
    q = temp$i
    a = quicksort(a, p, q-1)
    a = quicksort(a, q+1, r)
  }
  a
}

v = c(8, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1, 3, 2)
quicksort(v, 1, length(v))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Cheers,

alex

Comment: Ah! I knew it had to be something specific with how R passes values as to why it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't modifying `a` within the functions `quicksort` or `partition`.  R (in effect) passes by value.  When you modify the value within the function, you're modifying a copy.  This modification does not persist after the function has returned.

So you need to return the partitioned value instead of modifying within `parition` in order for this to work.

For example, `partition` could return a list of two vectors, the two partitions.  And you can then call `quicksort` on each of these returned vectors.